# Set "secure" flag on Mojolicious session

Tags: perl, mojolicious, mojolicious-lite

How does one set the secure flag on a Mojolicious session cookie? I'd like to be able to access it locally also on my test environment which does not run on https.

I've read the [Sessions](http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious/Sessions) docs and the [app->session](http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious#sessions) one, and tried (in a `Mojolicious::Lite` app)

```
app->sessions->secure(0)
```

but to no result.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by *"to no result"* are you clear that `$app->sessions->secure(0)` will *disable* security so that cookies may be sent over HTTP? What behaviour are you getting?

Comment: @borodin - 2 things show that nothing has happened: the cookie is not accessible to JavaScript and it’s still showing as “secure” in the browser debugger window. And yes, I’m aware - that’s only in the development environment.

Comment: I think you need to create an [*MCVE*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that allows us to experiment with your code. Otherwise we will be making far too many guesses and assumptions to be able to recreate your situation properly. You may well find your own solution in the process of creating it.